# Mark required formControls before Validation when using Reactive Forms in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

We would like to give visual feedback to the user, which field is required, *before* validation, e.g. by highlighting the field blue.

We are using *Reactive Forms* to validate the user's input:

```
export class MyFormComponent {
  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required ],
      city: ''
    });
  }
}
```

with the template

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Name:
      <input class="form-control" formControlName="name">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>City:
      <input class="form-control" formControlName="name">
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

The whole template will be generated from a model later on. Because of this, we would like to keep the template as "pure" as possible.

But: For highlighting required fields via CSS, I need either a class or an attribute (*required*) on the input-element. It would be nice, if Angular could set one (or both) to the `input`-Element, when the corresponding `FormControl` is given an Validator of `required`.

In the above example, I would have to add a class `required` or the attribute `required` *by hand* to the `input`-Element to make this CSS work:

```
.form-control[required], .form-control.required {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

**Is there a way to attach class or attribute to the DOM-Element automatically, when a validator is set to the corresponding `FormControl`?**

Comment: If I understand you correctly you can attach your css to the classes `.ng-invalid` and `.ng-valid`?

Comment: Yes, I can. But a field can be invalid or valid when a user enters the page, regardless if it's required or not. So highlighting all invalid fields does not do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So angular does not have anything called as getValidators. There is an open issue here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13461

However, here is something you can do to get all formControls with the required validator. (Not my code: Mentioned by someone on the open issue)

```
getValidators(_f) {
  return Object.keys(_f).reduce((a, b) => {
    const v = _f[b][1];
    if (v && (v === Validators.required || v.indexOf(Validators.required) > -1)) {
      if (!a[b]) { a[b] = {}; }
      a[b]['required'] = true;
    }
    return a;
  }, {});
}

const _f = {
  id: [],
  name: [null, Validators.required],
  phone: [],
  email: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]]
};
this.frmMain = this._fb.group(_f);
console.log(this.getValidators(_f));    // {name: {"required": true}, email: {"required": true}}
```

Once you have the list of all controls with the required validator, you can just loop through them and apply styles accordingly.

I hope the only issue was getting controls with required validator? If yes, this should resolve the issue.